# pm2 closes when I log out from powershell SSH session

Tags: powershell, ssh, pm2

I am using pm2 to start and monitor a node application.

I SSH into my VPS through powershell, run `pm2 start pnpm --name $APPNAME -- start`.

I've created a pm2 startup script, and ran `pm2 save`

My understanding is that pm2 should just run in the background, rerun the app if it ever crashes, and resurrect the saved processes on a server restart. However, whenever I close my SSH session, pm2 gets sent a signal to stop, and my process is stopped. Does anyone have any insight into why this might be, and how I can work around it?

Comment: The question is 'can you start any other process that will continue after you logout?' For instance, do 'node server.js &' and check if it works after you logout.